# Generate dropdown based on number of elements in an array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

Suppose I have an array as:

```
const nameArray = ["apple","banana","orange"]
```

I tried to generate drowndown based on number of elements in the array, for this I tried as:

```
    <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="Select Vendors" >Select Vendors</InputLabel>
        <Select name="vendors" id="vendors">
        {nameArray.forEach(element => {
            <MenuItem value={element}>element</MenuItem>        
        })}
        </Select>
    </FormControl>
```

But it gives me error: **Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression**

What else could be donw to generate dropdown based on element?

Comment: `nameArray.map` instead of `.forEach`, and `return` the MenuItem or remove brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const nameArray = ["apple","banana","orange"];

<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel id="Select Vendors" >Select Vendors</InputLabel>
    <Select name="vendors" id="vendors">
    {nameArray.map(element => {
        return <MenuItem value={element}>element</MenuItem>;   
    })}
    </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help , but could you please also tell me why .forEach doesn't work but .map works

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return anything. It just iterates over the array only. To print elements in JSX inside curly braces, you should return something. `Array.map` transforms the existing array to another array and returns the transformed array.